# Scaling displays with libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a simple game that allows a user to move vertically by wall jumping where the boundaries of the wall are defined by the left and right of the screen. The physical device I'm testing on is an LG G2 with a resolution of 1920x1080. I'm also testing on a virtual device with the resolution of 800x480.

My issue is that the game doesn't scale between the two devices. When the player jumps in a parabolic arc from left to right it takes less time on the smaller display than the large one because they don't scale and indeed, assets are twice the size on the smaller resolution.

I'm instantiating my camera and viewport as follows:

```
...
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(480, 800);

    viewport = new StretchViewport(9, 16, camera);
...
```

... but no matter which viewport or camera I choose nothing seems to scale the display. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

My `create()` now looks like this:

```
...
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, screenHeight/screenWidth);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    camera.update();

    viewport = new ExtendViewport(100, 200, camera);
...
```

And my `render()` now looks like this:

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

The issue I'm having now is that nothing seems to appear on the screen. I think the camera is in the right position because things are being drawn, I just can't see them. The game plays as normal when I check various values as I debug. Any ideas?

Comment: how do you use the camera? do you do viewport.update(width, height) in the resize method? The StrechViewport has a virtual viewport size and this should be stretched/shrinked to fit any screen. The gameplay should not change at all, depending on the device.

Comment: I do that in the resize method but it doesn't do anything. I can actually comment out those two lines of code above and the game behaves the exact same.

Comment: So... you aren't using your camera at all? Usually you use it via `spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)`.

Comment: I've updated my code as it currently stands with my current issue.

Comment: After creating your `viewport` you need to call update on it.

Comment: Still no elements are visible on the screen.